# How to get the direct value associated with a key in a dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift

```
var names = ["1": "2", "3": "4"]
print(names["1"])`
```

It prints: `Optional("2")`

I know that I can get the value by putting an exclamation mark at the end but is there any way to get the value directly without putting the exclamation mark?

Comment: So what do you expect to happen when there is no value associated with the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `if let` or `guard let`.

```
if let name1 = names["1"] {
   print(name1)
}
```

OR

```
guard let name1 = names["1"] else {
    return
}
print(name1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = ["1": "2", "3": "4"]

for (key, value) in names {
print(value)
}
```

Output will be:

2

4

You can replace "key" with "_" to silence the warning.

Comment: Or `for values in names.values { ... }`